# Pentaho - Replace variable value - .kjb

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I have a job that calls two transformations and depending on a situation I need to update the value of a variable that is received as parameter:

[image]

I'm using Set Variables component but is not changing the value of variable. Does anybody know how can I achieve? I'm using Pentaho server 8.1.0.0-365 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to create a new transformation to assign the value to the variable:

[image]

[image]